# How to parse string to decimal with currency symbol?

Tags: c#, .net, string, type-conversion, globalization

I have no idea why this is not working:

```
string s = "12,00 €";
var germanCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
decimal d;
if (decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, germanCulture, out d))
{
    // i want to get to this point
    Console.WriteLine("Decimal value: {0}", d);
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `NumberStyles.Currency` instead of `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`

```
if (decimal.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Currency, germanCulture, out d))
```

and the output for you code would be:

```
Decimal value: 12.00
```

Comment: A little more information to explain why this is so:
NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol only permits the currency symbol to be ignored as part of the parsing process. The additional whitespace and decimal separator require additional flags to enable them: AllowDecimalPoint and AllowTrailingWhite. Currency combines these flags (and a few others) [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-SG", false), "{0:c0}", 123423.083234);
```

It will convert 123423.083234 to $1,23,423 format.

Comment: I needed to parse a string that contains a currency symbol to decimal. You are converting a given decimal to string. So that's a different requirement. However, it is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this doesn't work with the bitcoin symbol and other cryptocurrency symbols yet, unfortunately. I tried both ways.

Sharplab proof: [link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AcQBsB7AIwEMqBLALweGZqgG488MAZiIBvPEQkl06UZLlFx8iQDcGYIgGciAXiIAiALSB+OEGYAHGUEBWPX1xKJipXACmAY2YBbJmQAKajRcACg0YIgA5CE86FzAAZWAATyoXDTIAYQgwMBcoN0SwzKpgLJcASSgAMxoyCtUwZgYoYCKSnIBKOwciVw9vKj8A4NCIqJj4pJS0gEEqWgB3TOzc/LjE6JoqQohi0orq2qh6xubW0s6nIgBfPCugA===)

A workaround in my case (I have a minus sign followed by the bitcoin ฿ symbol) would be to do
a .Where() on string ignoring everything except numbers and minus sign... But if you want general validation... Well then you'll have to hardcode these bitcoin etc symbols somewhere