# TryParse failing with currency string type for parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

My form has textbox that holds a number for quantity.  then in the textchanged event that number is placed in a label's text property with currency value (ex: $4.00). In my button click event I am trying to add all the values from the labels.  When using the following code tryparse fails everytime

```
int num1;
string text = lbl85x11bwsub.Text;
if (int.TryParse(text, out num1)) 
{
     MessageBox.Show(num1.ToString()); //testing
}
else
{
      MessageBox.Show("it failed");
}
```

but if I try the same thing using the textbox's text property it works.

```
int num2;
if (int.TryParse(txt85x11bw.Text, out num2)) 
{
     MessageBox.Show(num2.ToString());
}
else
{
      MessageBox.Show("it failed");
 }
```

Comment: sorry but are you sure that `lbl85x11bwsub.Text` contains valid integer (string)?

Comment: In the second code, you are getting the string from the txt, not the lbl.

Comment: You just said the label contains the "$" character .. that can't be converted to an int.

Comment: @scartag:  Neither can the string `4.00` with `int.TryParse`...

Comment: @AustinSalonen Yeah .. silly me ... i saw the "$" character and immediately stopped processing :)

Answer (score 14):

@Frederik Gheysels give you almost complete answer on your question except one tiny thing. In this case you should use NumberStyles.Currency because your number can be not only not integer, but also contain thousand and decimal separators. While NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol will only care about currency sign. On the other hand NumberStyles.Currency  [is a composite number style.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) Which can allow almost all the other separators.

So, this expression, probably, will works:

```
Decimal.TryParse(text, 
    NumberStyles.Currency, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    out result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Decimal.TryParse(text, 
    NumberStyles.Currency, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    out result);
```

instead.
The number you're trying to parse, is:

- not an integer
- contains a currency symbol

Comment: what happens when you leave out the currency symbol from your string ?  Are you sure that the currency symbol that is present in the string, is the actual currency symbol defined in your culture settings ? ...  (Debugging 101)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumberStyles.Currency` instead of `NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol`

See [How to parse string to decimal with currency symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878464/how-to-parse-string-to-decimal-with-currency-symbol)