# How to Convert textedit (Currency) into decimal in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, currency

In my form textedit i get value "₹ 7,245.00" now I want to convert this textedit value into decimal for total calculation. I used this code but getting error like this "Invalid Input String"

```
 decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);
```

How to solve this ?. I need 7,245.00 only.

Comment: I would recommend using the approach from the post @Junaith commented above, but you could however go the easy hacky way and do a Price.Text.SubString(1) if you know that the symbol would always be at position 0; before converting to decimal.

Comment: That or regex away anything but numbers, the period, comma and minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your text contains a non-parsable character `₹`. Strip it before parsing, or parse with `AllowCurrencySymbol`: [How to parse string to decimal with currency symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878464/how-to-parse-string-to-decimal-with-currency-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
    string s1 = Price.Text.Trim().Substring(1);
    decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(s1);
```

as it is working fine for me...

```
    string s = "₹ 7,245.00";
    string s1 = s.Substring(1);
    decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(s1);
```